# mysql data to javascript object

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

Hello fellow StackOverflowers!

I have some information in a database that I need pulled out and put into javascript context.

I am successfully getting the data with mysqlli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "censored", "censored", "censored");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM foodstuff";
```

The foodstuff_categories contain:

- id, category_id, category and language.
- example: 1,  1, vegetables, en

The foodstuff contain:

- id, category, name and language
- example : 1, 1, potato, en

category in foodstuff is the same as category_id in foodstuff_categories.

foodstuff_categories contains the name of the category whilst foodstuff contains the name of the foodstuff.

**Problem:**
I need to make an object out of the database data that is compliant with jQuery UI's autosuggestion widget which looks like this:

```
 var availableTags =
 [
    { label: "veal"  , category: "meat" },
    { label: "potato", category: "vegetables" }
 ];
```

I am currently calling the php script with:

```
$.get('php/dbFoods.php', function(data)
{
    //gotta do something with that data! :)
});
```

**my thoughts**
I think i need to join some information in the select statement and then find a smart way to turn that data into an object compliant with the jquery UI widget.

**appended inoformation after answer has been given**

Use the alteriative answer in the accepted answer.

The jquery ui autocomplete from database requires more information than is immediately apparent! Refer to this page: http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-a-remote-database-and-php/

Comment: Like... JSON? Just use `json_encode`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is getting the array in such a state that i can json encode it :)

Comment: So you actually want the SQL query to do it?

Comment: I basically want what scessor posted, i'm getting a syntax error though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
...
$query = "
  SELECT fc.`category` AS category, f.`name` AS label
  FROM `foodstuff` AS f 
  INNER JOIN `foodstuff_categories` AS fc 
  ON fc.`category_id` = f.`category`
";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$rows = array();
while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $data;
}
// convert iso to utf8 data 
function encodeArray($array) {
    foreach ($array as $index => $row) {
        $array[$index] = array(
            'category' => mb_check_encoding($row['category'], 'UTF-8') ? $row['category'] : utf8_encode($row['category'])
            , 'label' => mb_check_encoding($row['label'], 'UTF-8') ? $row['label'] : utf8_encode($row['label'])
        );
    }
    return $array;
}
echo json_encode(encodeArray($rows));
```

Alternative:

```
...
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection); // from now on return data in utf8 format (only)
$query = "
  SELECT fc.`category` AS category, f.`name` AS label
  FROM `foodstuff` AS f 
  INNER JOIN `foodstuff_categories` AS fc 
  ON fc.`category_id` = f.`category`
";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$rows = array();
while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

The query builds an associative array with the given structure. [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) builds an [JSON](http://json.org/) for the client. jQuery can automatically convert the JSON to an object which could be parsed by javascript. Possibly you should add the *dataType* parameter (here *'json'*) to your [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('php/dbFoods.php', function(data)
{
    //gotta do something with that data! :)
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Exactly what i need... do i still need to eval the json data on the javascript?

PHP gives me this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in censored on line 20

Comment: Ehm line 20 is: while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc())

Comment: Is it the query causing the problems?

Now I get a lot of these:
Warning: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in /customers/6/5/8/gybbel.dk/httpd.www/php/dbFoods.php on line 24

which is echo json_encode($rows);

Comment: On the individual tables its utf8_danish_ci, on the general collation it's utf8_general_ci.

The database will contain danish characters like æøå but the general utf8 should be able to handle that? Should i change it to something else?

edit: yes the SQL works, just tested it! :) i really appreciate your help.

Comment: The alternative script works! :) however I'm getting æøå as "\u00f8". Is there a way to set this in phpmyadmin instead of calling "SET NAMES 'utf8'" ?

Comment: Actually...when jquery recieves it, it doesn't seem to mind the  "\u00f8" and converts it correctly! :) but is there a way to put the utf8 convertion on the db? Or is it a silly question?

When the JS receives it i get this.source is not a function:
$.get('php/dbFoods.php', function(data)
 {
    availableTags = data;
 }, 'json');

Comment: Most likely there is a better solution for the utf8 encoding but at the moment I have no alternative. Can you show me the code which includes _this.source_?

Comment: I sure can! It's the jQuery UI autocomplete with categories: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories If i echo out the string from php and (manually) load it into the autocomplete it works, but when it attempts to convert it to a JS object it seems to fail. Example output is [{"category":"Gr\u00f8ntsager","label":"Kartofler"},{"category":"Gr\u00f8ntsager","label":"Tomater"}]

Comment: Try something like: `$(...).autocomplete({source: 'php/dbFoods.php'});`

Comment: Alternative: `$(...).autocomplete({ source: function(request, setter) { $.get('php/dbFoods.php', function(response) { var data = $.parseJSON(response); setter(data); }, 'json'); } });`

Comment: Holy crap that worked you're a genius! :) I would still love to know how to convert it to a js object for future use if you wouldn't mind... edit: although now it lists the whole thing and doesn't intelligently filter... that's a problem.

Comment: You can do this with e.g. with [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), this converts the json string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14275/discussion-between-eirinn-and-scessor)

Answer (score 3):

Create an array resembling the structure you'd like in your JSON and then [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) that array.

If your query only returns the stuff you want in your array, simply fetch all rows and store them in an array and then [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) it.